# How to run async function before AWS Lambda handler triggers

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

How it would be possible to run an asynchronous function outside of AWS Lambda handler and make use of its output in the handler function? I need to initialize various DB connections asynchronously before the handler function runs. That way the active DB connections can survive upon container reuse.

Example:

```
var i = 'immediate start';
setTimeout(function(){
  i = 'delayed start';
}, 5000);
module.exports.handler = function (event, context, callback) {
  console.log(i); 
  //outputs `immediate start` whereas I need to have  i = `delayed start` here.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You would have to create a promise and then resolve the promise whenever your callback function inside of `setTimeout()` is triggered. Like so:

```
module.exports.handler = function (event, context, callback) {
    var i = 'immediate start'; 
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         setTimeout(() => { 
             i = 'delayed start'; 
             resolve()
         })
     })
     .then(()=>console.log(i))
}
```